# Moq - Method evaluation with nullable parameter throws null exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I know that I can new up an object and pass it in but I'm trying to match the syntax and patterns since the value is never actually used.

**Implementation:**

```
public interface IDemoProvider
{
    string GetStringById(int? id);
}

public interface IDemoService
{
    bool Validate(ServiceRequest request);
}

public class ServiceRequest
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public int? bar { get; set; }
}

public class SomeDemoProvider : IDemoProvider
{
    public virtual string GetStringById(int? id)
    {
        if (id != null)
            return "success";
        else
            return "else";
    }
}

public class BaseDemoService : IDemoService
{
    public IDemoProvider Provider { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Validate(ServiceRequest request)
    {
        if (request.bar == null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}

public class SomeDemoService : BaseDemoService
{
    public SomeDemoService(IDemoProvider provider)
    {
        Provider = provider;
    }

    public virtual string Post(ServiceRequest request)
    {
        if (!Validate(request))
            throw new Exception("Invalid Request");
        return Provider.GetStringById(request.bar);
    }
}
```

**Test Code:**

```
[TestFixture]
public class ProgramTests
{
    [Test]
    public void SomeDemoServiceTest()
    {
        var mockProvider = new Mock<IDemoProvider>();
        mockProvider.Setup(p => p.GetStringById(It.IsAny<int?>())).Returns(() => "success");

        object[] args = { mockProvider.Object };

        var mockService = new Mock<SomeDemoService>(args) {CallBase = true};
        mockService.Setup(s => s.Validate(It.IsAny<ServiceRequest>())).Returns(true);

        string result = mockService.Object.Post(It.IsAny<ServiceRequest>());

        Assert.AreEqual("success", result);
    }
}
```

**Issue**

This results in a `NullReferenceException` which makes sense since it's trying to resolve `request.Id` while running which is null at the request level.

However, if I replace the parameter with `null`, it works fine:

```
return Provider.GetStringById(null);
```

My question here is whether there's some way to make the interceptor recognize before evaluating the expression that it should just return the value instead of trying to evaluate the expression.

I could mock out the rest of the request object but it seems silly since the values are never used according to the test. The real question here is whether I should be writing the code or the test differently to avoid this scenario or if I'm over complicating an issue with a simple workaround.

Comment: The evaluation happens *before* the method is ever invoked. So - no, it's not possible to have that happen without some *serious* pre-processing of your libraries. Your code in `Post` should handle the case where `request` is null. If it's invalid for `request` to be null, then your test is invalid (it should be a test asserting it's invalid to pass a null request). This is an XY problem - and luckily for you - this behaviour is exposing either a bug in your code, or a misunderstanding of what you're testing

Comment: Also, I assume `GetStoreByStoreReferenceId` should be `GetObjectById`?

Comment: You need to rewrite this question. In its current form it is unclear. provide a [mcve] that can be used to recreate the problem.

Comment: @Rob, when the service is actually running normally, the validation logic would fire and kick out an exception before this point so you are correct in what I should be doing. What I'm trying to understand is how to mock a service properly.
I mock the validation logic to return back no errors in order to bypass because I want to test specifically what happens if the GetObjectById returns null and I was hoping to do so in a way without building out a request itself, instead only mocking the methods before it.

Comment: @Nkosi appreciate the suggestion, added the code to reproduce this in a local environment. Been using SF for a long time, first question so appreciate any feedback on asking better questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing it wrong.

If you are trying to exercise the method under test then this line...

```
string result = mockService.Object.Post(It.IsAny<ServiceRequest>());
```

is being used incorrectly. You would use `It.IsAny<ServiceRequest>()` as part of the setup. In the case of how you are trying to use it, it will result in `null` in the `Validate` method

```
request.bar == null
```

because the `It.IsAny`expression is not actually passing anything into the method.

Read up on how to use Moq via the [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use it when testing.

Rewrite the test as

```
public void SomeDemoServiceTest() {
    //Arrange
    var mockProvider = new Mock<IDemoProvider>();
    mockProvider.Setup(p => p.GetStringById(It.IsAny<int?>())).Returns(() => "success");

    var mockService = new Mock<SomeDemoService>(mockProvider.Object) { CallBase = true };
    mockService.Setup(s => s.Validate(It.IsAny<ServiceRequest>())).Returns(true);

    var request = new ServiceRequest();

    //Act
    var result = mockService.Object.Post(request);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("success", result);
}
```

And the test should pass.

Comment: _You would use It.IsAny<ServiceRequest>() as part of the setup. In the case of how you are trying to use it, it will result in null in the Validate method_

This is exactly what I was missing. I read through a couple tutorials and watched some videos on this but it seemed like they were mocking all the things so it was a bad example to follow. Thanks @Nkosi